# Cambiar tamaño por clases

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito cambiar el tamaño de varias imágenes respecto a su clase pero no funciona aunque básicamente copie el código que use para cambiarlo con el ID que si funciona

```js
    function TamaClas () {
        if (document.getElementById("TamClas").checked == true) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ImgLing").style.width = "90px";
        } else if (document.getElementById("TamClas").checked == false) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ImgLing").style.width = "50px";
        }
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="TamClas" onclick="TamaClas();">
    <label for="TamClas"></label>
    <br>
    <img src="HtmlClas.png" class="ImgLing" height="70">
    <img src="CssClas.png" class="ImgLing" height="70">
    <img src="JsClas.jpg" class="ImgLing" height="70">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de cambiar el tamaño de varias imágenes respecto a su clase es utilizar un bucle para recorrer cada una de ellas. Por ejemplo:

```js
  function TamaClas () {
        var imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName("ImgLing");
        if (document.getElementById("TamClas").checked == true) {
            for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
                imagenes[i].style.width = "90px";
            }
        } else if (document.getElementById("TamClas").checked == false) {
            for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
                imagenes[i].style.width = "50px";
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="TamClas" onclick="TamaClas();">
<label for="TamClas"></label>
<br>
<img src="HtmlClas.png" class="ImgLing" height="70">
<img src="CssClas.png" class="ImgLing" height="70">
<img src="JsClas.jpg" class="ImgLing" height="70">
```